# Integration the allure jenkins plugin with jenkins.groovy

Tags: jenkins, allure

I try to integrate the allure plugin for jenkins only with the pom.xml (i use maven) and jenkins.groovy files.
I do not have access to jenkins configuration with administration level.
Allure allready builds reports locally. But i do not know how to integrate to jenkins i.e.
what to add to jenkins.groovy.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: You can run jenkins locally https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the test report on the server not locally.

Comment: I meant you could use local jenkins instance where you can have administration permissions to develop and debug you pipeline.
For easier writing allure steps for jenkins pipeline you can use [snippet-generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator)